# Fitting a 2D transform to a set of points

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

I'm digitising some hand-drawn maps.  My method is to scan the map, import it into an SVG editor and trace over the features.  I then mark some datum points on the SVG, with metadata to indicate that they are datum points.  Then I find those same datum points on Google Maps to get their location in decimal lat/long and add those values to the metadata.  Note that the hand-drawn map is not necessarily oriented so that the Y axis points North.

So now I have two lists of vectors: $A$ is an 2xN matrix with the datum coordinates in SVG coordinates as $(x, y)$ and $B$ is a 2xN matrix with the datum coordinates as $(lng, lat)$.

I now want to find a rotation, scale and translation that will map coordinates from one space to the other, so that I can then transform the actual features on the map to lat/long.

I found [this method](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671) which uses SVD to obtain a rotation and translation matrix, but I'm not sure how well the SVD step will work when there is a scale involved as well.  To summarise the method:

1. Let $A_c$ and $B_c$ be the centroids of $A$ and $B$ (ie the arithmetic mean along each column).
2. Calculate the covariance matrix $H=(A-A_c)(B-B_c)^T$.
3. Do the SVD -- $U, S, V = SVD(H)$.
4. The rotation matrix is then $R = VU^T$.
5. The translation is $t=B-RA$

Can I then just calculate the scale as the mean along each column $S = \overline{B_c / (RA_c)}$ (where / is element-wise division)?  And then re-evaluate the translation as $t=B-diag(S)(RA)$?  Or does the scale need to be taken into account in the SVD somehow?

Answer (score 2):

The same website that you linked has an article that explains the inner workings of OpenCV's estimateRigidTransform function. I believe that's what you are looking for to compute the scale.

http://nghiaho.com/?p=2208

Assuming uniform scale (no shear), solve for [a, b, c, d] using 2 points:
$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & -y_1 & 1 & 0 \\ y_1 & x_1 & 0 & 1 \\ x_2 & -y_2 & 1 & 0 \\ y_2 & x_2 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x’_1 \\ y’_1 \\ x’_2 \\ y’_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Where:
$$a = \cos(\theta)s$$
$$b = \sin(\theta)s$$
$$c = tx$$
$$d = ty$$

If you have 3 or more points, a simple least square solution can be obtained by doing a pseudo-inverse:
$$\begin{matrix} Ax & = & b \\ A{^T}Ax & = & A^{T}b \\x & =& (A{^T}A)^{-1}A{^T}b \end{matrix}$$